# adding two number in assembly X86_64 from user

Tags: nasm, x86-64, assemblies

```
section .data
    text1 db "Enter the first number :"
    text2 db "Enter the second number :"


section .bss
    num1 resb 2
    num2 resb 2
    sum_temp resb 4 


section .text
    global _start

_start:

    ; print : "Enter the first number: "
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, text1
    mov rdx, 24
    syscall

    ; get the first number from input
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rsi, num1
    mov rdx, 2
    syscall

    ; print: "Enter the second number: "
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, text2
    mov rdx, 25
    syscall

    ; get the second number from input
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rsi, num2
    mov rdx, 2
    syscall


    ; load two numbers into registers for addition 
    mov rbx, [num1]
    mov rcx, [num2]


    ; add the two number and save the result in rbx
    add rbx, rcx

    ; show the result to the user
    mov [sum_temp], rbx
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, sum_temp
    mov rdx, 4
    syscall 

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

In this code I try to get two number from the user and add them together and finally show the answer. this is what I try to do:

first: show the user a message to enter the first number

second: get the first number

third: show the user a message to enter the second number

forth: second: get the second number

fifth: load numbers into two registers for addition

sixth: add the two numbers together

seventh: save the result back to memory

finally: show the user the answer

I enter 1 and 2 as inputs but the output is : c2

Please I'm completely new to this language. what mistake am I making?

Answer (score 1):

At "load two numbers into registers for addition", you load two qwords.

What is actually stored there however, are two 2-byte strings. So they're not only the wrong size, but also the wrong format. These strings get added by their code-point values, '1' = 0x31, '2' = 0x32, 'c' = 0x63, and that extra '2' shows up because reading a whole qword from `num1` reads `num2` as well (and also `sum_temp`). Two extra bytes are printed, but apparently didn't show up in the output.

Then you write a qword to `sum_temp`, that's more than the space reserved for it by the way, which is then printed as a string while it was still a plain integer (or it should have been a plain integer but is a mangled string, depending on how you look at it).

Convert your data to the right format for every step. You should be more careful with sizes too.

Comment: please I don't understand, would it be alright if you edited my code? please It's been 3 hours I'm killing myself

Comment: @KasraGH simply writing code for learners is usually seen as bad. I'm sure you can do it now that you know that the strings and integers here should be *converted* instead of just reinterpreted. Or you could implement string-addition. But either way make sure you use the data in a way that makes sense given its format.